# How to check whether a product is in the cart?

Tags: magento2

How to create a module that will check if there is an item in the basket?
Verification is needed on the product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this below code :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart 
) {
    $this->_cart = $cart;  
  }


public function getProductData()
{
    $productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($productInfo as $item){
       $item->getProductId();
       if($item->getProductId() == 'your_product_id')
       {
            echo "Item available in cart";
       }
       else
       {
            echo "Item not available in cart";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this code?

Comment: you can add in your block or controller.

Comment: What structure should be? I just do not understand what should be in the model and what should be in the block, etc.

Comment: Wherer you want to access this value?

Comment: On the product page

Comment: No. I mean in phtml file or contorller etc.? Do you have custom block which is used in product page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92139/discussion-between---and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: @РомаЛытарьYou can accept and upvote answer. If it's helpful for you.